# how to make special program run with different version of java from system?

Tags: java

My system need to use java 1.7. However, I need to run some old apps which require java1.6. Can I use shell script to let the old apps use correct java version?
Could the  $JAVA_HOME work?

I try to set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64`
However, it does not has any effect.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like using a shell script and `$JAVA_HOME` could work. What have you tried?

Comment: Also set $PATH too ?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` itself seems does not work. Do I need to set PATH?

Comment: I would just create a one line wrapper script and call the specific java virtual machine explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some systems there is a command that is called `java-config` or `java-config-2` that helps you selecting a java vm when you have multiple JDK or JRE versions installed with your system installer. But basically you want to call your java app with the `java` binary that should live somewhere near `$JAVA_HOME`. I would guess `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`.

The `$JAVA_HOME` helps the called `java` program finding it's libraries, but it doesn't help your command line finding the right java binary.

Comment: set $PATH works also. But I think directly call the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` is better.

Comment: That depends on how temporary you call your old app and if you need to use more tools from the `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, but to answer the question I thought it would be best to be most specific and let you decide about your PATH variable yourself ;)